# iOS 11 Xcode 9: CoreML linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, xcode9

I'm trying to capture photo using `AVFoundation`

Here is my code:

```
@objc func didTapCameraView() {
    self.cameraView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
    let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
    let previewFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: previewPixelType,
                         kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 160,
                         kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 160]
    settings.previewPhotoFormat = previewFormat
    if flashControlState == .off {
        settings.flashMode = .off
    } else {
        settings.flashMode = .on
    }
    cameraOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
}
```

but I'm getting same error every time.

[image]

If I comment the code inside methods then it builds fine.
Let me know what I missed.

**Update**:
using iPhone 6 iOS11

Build architectures

[image]

Snapshot while using physical device

[image]

Comment: But your log tells it was built on simulator. Is it same log for iPhone6 device?

Comment: @HwanghoKim : Consider it as device as in the device is issue is same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the explanation from Apple develop forum, Check this [link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/259270#259270)

This bug will be fixed later(unfortunately it still exists in ode 9 GM Version). 
Quote from Apple forum, we can use this workaround:

> As a workaround you can use the SwiftPrivate versions of these API by prepending each API with double underscore (`__`). For example, change `AVCaptureDevice.Format.supportedColorSpaces` to `AVCaptureDevice.Format.__supportedColorSpaces`.

I tested it and it works, and they said such workaround is considered  legitimate and is not considered SPI use.